# How to Create a Graph Traced by Parametrics

Tags: geometry, parametric

The question is as follows:

> What graph is traced by the parametric equation $(x,y) = (t, 4-t^2)$?

I am unsure as how I can create a graph given that parametric equation. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set $x = t$. Then $y = 4 - x^2$. What is this curve?

Comment: Would it be a parabola?

Comment: Yes. correct...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Eliminate $t$ from the following equations to get an equation $y(x)$.

$$x(t) = t$$
$$y(t) = 4-t^2$$